# The column name that you entered is already in use or reserved

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, site-column

I create a column, then I deleted this column. After that I create column with same name again and show me this message. How to solve this problem ?

[image]

Thank you previously..

Comment: try clearing your recycle bin in sharepoint

Comment: What I deleted does not appear in the recycle bin ?

Comment: it wont but try clearing it

Comment: You cannot fild deleted column in recycle bin as it is not an entity. its actually realted to schema

Comment: Try to find your previously created column using powershell if it exists then delete it. Then create your desired column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to find your previously created site column using powershell, if exists then remove it using Powershell.

You get more info from below links:

- https://shipoint.com/2012/06/07/removing-a-corrupted-site-column-in-sharepoint-2010/
- http://blog.sharepointsite.co.uk/2011/05/corrupt-site-column-cannot-be-deleted.html

Comment: Is there another way besides PowerSHell

Comment: Corrupted site column may be removed easily using powershell rather than another approaches.

Comment: These links are dead

Answer (score 2):

- Give some time after deletion of your column, then create a new
  column with same name
- If you still face the issue, take a template of the list and delete the list. Recreate the list and try creating your column

Comment: How time ??????

Comment: just 5 mins at the max. Actually you dont need the time but just a try.